# Make node display text after console.log() instead of <Buffer>

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, terminal

No matter what I do, node is displaying my console.log() text as a Buffer. Issue happens only in VSC powershell integrated terminal, in the browser message is displayed correctly.

client.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script>
    //calling the constructor which gives us the websocket object: ws
    let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000'); 
    console.log(ws);
    ws.onopen = (event) => ws.send("This is a message from client");
    ws.onmessage = (message) => console.log(message.data.toString('utf8'))
</script>

  <body>
    <h1>This is a client page</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
const http = require("http");
const websocket = require("ws");

//creating a http server
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end("I am connected");
});

const wss = new websocket.Server({ server });

wss.on("connection", (ws, req) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    ws.send("This is a message from server, connection is established");
  }, 3000);
  ws.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg.toString('utf-8'));
  });
});
//making it listen to port 8000
server.listen(8000);
```

I tried to access [data] property of WebSocket message, I also tried to use .toString('utf-8') with no success.

My Node version is `v18.13.0`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

in server.js file I wrote:

```
  ws.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg.toString('utf-8'));
  });
```

I should write `utf8` without `-`